# Admob interstitial ad gives an ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR on AdListener

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I try to ad Admob interstitial ad to my android app.

The google services are installed and work (I know it because banner ads do show).

The code runs this mehtod (on the UI thread):

```
private void cacheAds(List<String> types){      
    m_ad.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7000418520362131/3312518208");
    m_ad.setAdListener(new AdmobAdListener());

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
    .build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    m_ad.loadAd(adRequest); // Has to be called on uiThread
}
```

Where AdmobAdListener is as follows:

```
private class AdmobAdListener extends AdListener{
     public void onAdLoaded(){
         System.out.println(); // HERE I HAVE A BREAKPOINT
     }
     public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){
         System.out.println(); // HERE I HAVE A BREAKPOINT
     }
}
```

For some reason, as soon as the code runs, It stops at the breakpoint on the onAdFailedToLoad() method, when the errorCode == ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR.

Can someone think of why does it happen?

Comment: as it is mentioned: .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")

Comment: @Umitk, it's only a hash to be compared to the device's hash. Anyway I removed this line, and it still gets to ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: your method seems different to implement an interstitial ad. try to follow with this project and see result if it changes: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/interstitial

Answer (score -2):

This happens when the network speed is too slow on the phone. If you are on gprs or gsm connection speed. If you are using an emulator then check your internet speed before testing.